# Problem in Makefile forloop break statement

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

```
print:
    @for number in 10 11 12 13 14 15; do \
        ( echo "Number: $$number" ); \
        ( break ); \
        ( echo Break not working ); \
    done
```

**The output that i am getting**

```
Number: 10
Break not working
Number: 11
Break not working
Number: 12
Break not working
Number: 13
Break not working
Number: 14
Break not working
Number: 15
Break not working
```

**The output that i need :**

```
Number: 10
```

Comment: I'm puzzled. I can't find any reference to `@for` in the GNU make manual at https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html. Are you sure you are using GNU make? There is a `$(foreach ... )` that might help you.

Answer (score 2):

In the posted code the 'for' loop is executed in the shell (bash ?), not by the 'make' utility.

The problem with the bash script is that the 'break' statement is running in a sub-process - as it is placed inside parenthesis '( break '). As per bash manual, control-flow commands (while, if, for, return, ...) should executed in the "main" process. It is not possible to split them across processes.

Removing the '(' should solve the problem - the loop will stop after printing 'Number: 10'.

```
print:
    @for number in 10 11 12 13 14 15; do \
        ( echo "Number: $$number" ); \
        break ; \
        ( echo Break not working ); \
    done
```

As a side note, no need to put 'echo' statements in '( ... )'. It make the script fork unnecessary instances o bash.

Comment: Make uses `system()` call to execute commands, and it uses `/bin/sh`, you can't be sure it's a link to bash in all environments